# API - Entity Framework Core 2.1 return child information

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have written a Core 2.1 API that I'm attempting to retrieve the child test type information for a test.

Here is the parent TestInfo model class:

```
 public partial class TestInfo
{

    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string TestShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string TestLongDescription { get; set; }
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? TestLimitsId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestTypeInfo> TestTypeInfos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the child TestTypeInfo model class:

```
public partial class TestTypeInfo
{
    [ForeignKey("TestInfo")]
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TestTypeShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string TestTypeLongDescription { get; set; }
    public TestInfo TestInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller code.  I'm doing an include to pull in the test type info. I have the wrong syntax and could use some help...

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TestInfo> GetTestInfo()
    {
        var testinfo = _context.TestInfo.Include(t => t.TestTypeInfos);
        return _context.TestInfo.Include(t => t.TestTypeInfos).ToList();
    }
```

The problem is that the test type info being returned is based on the TestInfo TestID rather than the TestInfo TestTypeID.  Please see the image below.  Can someone tell me how to return the test type info based on the TestInfo TestTypeID of the test.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on your additional infos.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TestInfo> GetTestInfo()
{
    return _context.TestInfo
        .Select(c => new TestInfo()
        {
            TestId = c.TestId,
            TestShortDescription = c.TestShortDescription,
            TestLongDescription = c.TestLongDescription,
            TestTypeId = c.TestTypeId,
            TestLimitsId = c.TestLimitsId,
            TestTypeInfos = c.TestTypeInfos.Where(x => x.TestTypeId == c.TestTypeId).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Max - Based on your previous post I must be misinterpeting something.   I'm attempting to retrieve the child instance of TestTypeInfo based on the TestInfo TestTypeID.  I was thinking that the TestTypeInfo class properties values for the TestInfo TestTypeID would be placed in TestTypeInfos.  Removing the Foreign key maybe correct, but I receive an error message now stating :  Invalid column name 'TestInfoTestId'.

Comment: To clarify I want to use TestTypeID not TestID to link the 2 tables.  Just the foreign key (TestTypeID) not the primary key TestID.

Comment: @Paul What is the structure that you want? Do you want TestInfo to contain a list of TestTypeInfos?

Comment: TestInfo has a TestTypeID associated with it.  The TestInfo model class contains the TestTypeInfos property collection or single instance of the TestTypeInfo model class collection,  So all the properties and there values for the single instance that matches based on TestTypeID will be stored in the TestTypeInfos collection in TestInfo.  The reason I need the test type description is because the datagrid control I'm using groups on the parent collection information.  So instead of grouping by TestTypeID 2, it will group by Engine.  The other option is to right an aggregate function in the con

Answer (score 0):

Here's the explicit coding example I got to work:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TestInfo> GetTestInfo()
    {

       List<TestInfo> tstinfoIn = _context.TestInfo.ToList();
       List<TestTypeInfo> tsttypinfoIn = _context.TestTypeInfo.ToList();
       List<TestInfo> tstinfoComboOut = new List<TestInfo>();

       tstinfoComboOut = tstinfoIn
                       .Select(c => new TestInfo()
                       {
                           TestId = c.TestId,
                           TestShortDescription = c.TestShortDescription,
                           TestLongDescription = c.TestLongDescription,
                           TestTypeId = c.TestTypeId,
                           TestLimitsId = c.TestLimitsId,
                           TestTypeInfos = GetTestTypeInfo(tsttypinfoIn, c.TestTypeId)
                       })
                       .ToList();

        return tstinfoComboOut; 
    }
```

Here is the GetTestTypeInfo method to retrieve the children:

```
 public static List<TestTypeInfo> GetTestTypeInfo(List<TestTypeInfo> tsttypinfoIn, int parentTestTypeId)
    {
        return tsttypinfoIn
                .Where(c => c.TestTypeId == parentTestTypeId)
                .Select(c => new TestTypeInfo
                {
                    TestTypeId = c.TestTypeId,
                    TestTypeShortDescription= c.TestTypeShortDescription,
                    TestTypeLongDescription = c.TestTypeLongDescription
                })
                .ToList();
    }
```

Please let me know if there's a better way to do this...